# HTML5 video media controls panel customization

Tags: html5-video

I have a little bit of a conundrum. I am trying to change the shape of the media controls panel in an HTML5 video player, and so far the only thing I'm able to affect is the background color.

This is the CSS element:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
     background-color: #bbb;
}
```

```
<video width="350" height="240">
<source src="file-path" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

The problem is that no matter what I try, it's this default, ugly gray control panel
[image: player screenshot]

How do I change that? I'd like to changed the height, width, and the border radius.

CSS preferred.

Thanks

For the border radius, I've tried

```
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
```

... but it's not working, even with the !important flag.

I've also tried using height to affect the height, but height but that's not working either.

Comment: Code seems right. Just confirming - You are using webkit based browser for testing right ? (Chrome, Edge ... )

Comment: Yessir. I sure am. I just can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: There is a high chance that the pseudo-element customization has been deprecated in some recent Chrome update. I cannot find any official documentation though.

Comment: If that is indeed the case, you can hide the default controls and control the media via absolutely positioned custom controls bar - styling it with CSS and adding functionality with JS

Comment: @TechDex If you solved your problem, post the answer below and accept it. Don't put the answer in the question

Comment: Roger that @j08691. That's etiquette I'll have to remember. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem solved:** Thanks to VC-One's reply I was able to fix the problem, but not by disabling controls and creating my own buttons, but by adding the *video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure* to the CSS.

When I started customizing the HTML5 player, I took the parameters from an HTML5 video page, but the video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure wasn't one of the items. When VC-One had that in his response, pointinged out that the height goes in the panel and width goes in the enclosure, I was able to solve the issue by adjusting my css like so:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure {
    width:100%;
    background-color:transparent;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px !important;
    border-radius: 1px !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-bottom:-20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
    background-color: #eee;
    height:35px !important;
}
```

I made the enclosure background transparent, and set the background color in the panel, and adjusted all of the other elements, including border radius in the enclosure.

Now I have a pretty player on my site!

[image: pretty html5 player]

Thanks everyone, especially you VC-One.

Answer (score 1):

> *"I am trying to change the shape of the media controls panel in an HTML5 video player"*

I suggest you just **turn off** `controls` and create your own custom graphics which are placed (inside a container) in the same Div as the video object itself. Through the Styling of their container, they can be overlaid above the video object.

> *"I'd like to change the `height`, `width`, and the `border-radius`."*

At the `video::-webkit-media-controls ...` section,

- height is adjusted at the `-panel` parameter.
- width is adjusted at the `-enclosure` parameter.

For example:

```
<style>

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel 
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    border-radius: 10%;
    height: 30%;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure
{
    width: 90%;
}

</style>
```

A more fuller example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>

video::-webkit-media-controls-panel 
{
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 255);
    border-radius: 10%;
    height: 30%;

    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 20%;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure
{
    width: 90%;
}

</style>

<body>

<video width="350" height="240" oncontextmenu="return false;"
playsinline muted autoplay loop
disablepictureinpicture
controls controlsList="nodownload noplaybackrate noremoteplayback ">
<source src="file-path" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PS: Let me know if this code works on your version of Chrome (if not, then tell me your Chrome version number for testing).

Comment: Hey. I was able to fix it by adding the video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure to the CSS.

I took the parameters from an HTML5 video page, but the video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure parameter wasn't one of the items.

I had updated my answer with the fix but someone edited it back to exclude it

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the CSS proposed by TechDex looks like if you pair it with either the HTML proposed by VC.One or the most basic HTML with an appropriate file path and file type:

```
<video controls>
<source src=file_path type=file_type>
</video>
```

[result using CSS from TechDex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9VFi.png)

Anyone who wants to claim that these solutions do work should provide a link to a webpage that will let anyone inspect the HTML and the CSS and see how it is rendered by Chrome and Chromium.

The interesting question is who would have an incentive to spread false information about how to get Chrome and the Chromium-based browsers to display an HTML5 video control correctly. I rendered these images with Chrome Version 120.0.6099.129 and confirmed that they are the same on Brave Version 1.61.109 Chromium: 120.0.6099.144 and Opera Version 13.5.2 (Build 22G91) 13.5.2 Chromium version:120.0.6099.130.

Of course, it is possible (but unlikely) that those solutions worked back in Apr 2023. But in that case, who would have an incentive to make sure that they don't work 8 months later?

Comment: If you want to see live versions of the purported solutions offered by VC.one and TechDex, go to media.paulromer.net and follow the links to the two pages that implement the code they propose. Neither is close to working in an acceptable way.  Neither looks even remotely like the image that posted here.