# HTML5 video-player progress bar strange look in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video, angular15

I have a angular 15 project, where i use html5-video player.

Before playback starts, progress bar looks like this:

[Progress bar before playback starts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWl3U.png)

and while video is playing, progress bar looks like this:

[Progress bar after playback has started](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skGSy.png)

This is only Chrome related problem. Firfefox and IE works ok. Any info what might be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be aware that someone seems to be spreading disinformation about how to get Chrome/Chromium to correctly display an HTML video control.

See my replies [to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76084811/html5-video-media-controls-panel-customization/77742955#77742955): [HTML5 video media controls panel customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76084811/html5-video-media-controls-panel-customization/77742955#77742955)

Second, I can confirm on macOS the behavior that you report. Using a page with minimal styling:

- both Safari and Firefox will display a basic HTML5 video element appropriately;
- Chrome and Chromium display it with the excessively tall black bar that you display. I have tested with Chrome Version 120.0.6099.129 and confirmed that the look is the same on Brave Version 1.61.109 Chromium: 120.0.6099.144 and Opera Version 13.5.2 13.5.2 Chromium version:120.0.6099.130.

It may be relevant that Google.com would prefer that everyone post their videos on YouTube. To protect the YouTube monopoly, it might want to make it difficult for someone like you to display a video that you host elsewhere.

My suggestion is that you warn viewers that the video control will not render correctly on Chrome and Chromium-based browsers and recommend that they switch to a browser that undermining the user experience. On macOS, both Safari and Firefox do a much better job of rendering the basic video control.

I have not confirmed what the results are on Windows, but I'd be willing to bet that Edge makes the video control look just as bad as Chrome and Chromium do on macOS; and that Firefox does a reasonable job of rendering the control even if you do not customize it with any JavaScript or CSS.

It would be helpful if someone with a Windows machine could check and post a description of what they find. But then again, how will we know if this report is from someone who is telling the truth, or someone who is spreading disinformation?

Comment: The look of the default video player for Microsoft Edge is the same as the ugly look on Chrome. Firefox looks the same on Microsoft as on macOS.

Comment: If you want to see the basic video player that different browsers show when you insert an HTML video tag with no special CSS, go to this web site: media.paulromer.net. There are also pages there that show live versions of the false information that someone is spreading about how to improve the look on Chrome and Chromium.